# Symbolic Link git Submodule To Reference Files

Tags: git, symlink

So here is what I'm trying to do. I have a Unity 3D project for my reusable code. And I want to add this to my other projects that I house in git.

So let's say I have a project 'foo'.
I want to clone foo and then add my reusable scripts as a sub-module;
then I want a symbolic link to the folder that contains all the reusable scripts in my sub-module and one that exists in project foo's asset folder.
So when I make a change in my project, I could push my changes to my sub-module project.

This is probably very confusing, please let me know if I need to be more specific and I will try to do better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to separate the two environments:

- the git clone one, where you have foo and foo/script submodule:

  ```
  git clone foo /url/of/foo
  git submodule add /url/of/script
  git add .
  git commit -m "Add script as submodule of foo"
  git push
  ```
- the working environment, where you set your symlinks to foo and script scripts.

  ```
  cd somewhere/else
  ln -s /path/to/foo/file1
  ln -s /path/to/foo/scripts/scrip1
  ...
  ```

That way, once you have modified scripts, you can go back in foo, and do a `git push --recurses-submodules=check`, in order to make sure you have added/push both foo/scripts and foo.

Comment: Just so that I can understand. I add my 'reusables' as a sub-module of project 'foo'. Then I create a working directory with symbolic links to both projects to build the structure that I want?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but someone wouldn't be able to pull my repo and just begin working with this method, this symbolic link trick would need to be performed on each machine where we clone?

Also, will these symbolic link commands work on directories, not just files?

Comment: @Repareman " Correct me if I'm wrong, but someone wouldn't be able to pull my repo and just begin working with this method": yes, your repo would need to provide a script which would do the setup for you. Symlinks works for folders too. I am not saying this is ideal, I am just trying to answer your original requirement "I want a symbolic link to the folder that contains all the reusable scripts in my sub-module and one that exists in project foo's asset folder". Not sure why you need that, but if you do... my answer stands.